# Magento 2.1.8/2.1.9: Unable to create subcategory

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.1.8

I am able to create new root categories (and sub-categories of those), but if I try to create a new subcategory in "**Default Category**" (or any of its subcategories), I receive the following exception:

> *main.CRITICAL: InvalidArgumentException: indexMethod must be one of  in /home/site/websites/www.mysite.com/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/TemporaryTableService.php:104*

It may or may not be related, but the `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` table is completely empty.

I have tried **reindexing**, **clearing caches**, **compiling**, etc. All to to no avail.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Is this a fresh install?

Comment: It's not, no.The categories existed (and the functionality was working) in Magento 2.1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user dakzilla over on GitHub had the same issue, and his solution worked for me.

During the upgrade from 2.1.7 to 2.1.8 (in my case), app/etc/di.xml was not updated properly.

Adding the following lines to the file (after comparing my file to that in the official download) and recompiling got rid of the errors.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\TemporaryTableService">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="allowedIndexMethods" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="HASH" xsi:type="string">HASH</item>
      <item name="BTREE" xsi:type="string">BTREE</item>
    </argument>
    <argument name="allowedEngines" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="INNODB" xsi:type="string">INNODB</item>
      <item name="MEMORY" xsi:type="string">MEMORY</item>
      <item name="MYISAM" xsi:type="string">MYISAM</item>
    </argument>
  </arguments>
</type>
```